# More tag synonyms: [noun] and [существительные], [род] and [gender], [grammar] and [грамматика]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm in doubt about tag [noun] - it has only [one question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/why-does-the-dictionary-not-have-a-gender-for-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B) associated with it and possibly should be remapped to [nouns].

But I'm sure that [род] and [gender], [grammar] and [грамматика] should be made synonyms.
By the way [grammar] has 10 questions tagged and [грамматика] has 40 associated questions.

Here is a list of tag pairs I have found so far:

- [род] and [gender]
- [grammar] and [грамматика]
- [prefixes] and [приставки]
- [stylistics] and [стилистика]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, the tag synonyms have been created.

Comment: No problem, I got nice Tumbleweed badge for this question!

Comment: @Artemix Ahah good. :)